# Purpose of Function returns only boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery, minifiedjs

Somewhere in jQuery I have seen 2 functions that returns only `boolean` like below.

```
function h(){
   return !0;
}

function r(){
   return !1; 
}
```

What is the purpose of doing this, while Boolean can be written directly?

Comment: Obfuscation, perhaps?

Comment: I think reading debug version might help you understand better.

Comment: @Downvoter - yeah, this code looks like expanded minified code.

Comment: @Downvoter yeah, so does this mean that this functions won't be in original unminified code ?

Comment: Maybe. Depends on how the obfuscated code was created and if it is obfuscation at all. But yes, maybe. After all, my comment is just a guess out of the blue, therefore it's not an answer but a comment.

Comment: @Downvoter thanks though. Yes it was minified code , so maybe you are right. :)

Answer (score 3):

Economy of characters.

Having a 3 character function that returns true or false takes less characters than doing an exact comparison.

```
var a = false;
if (a === r()) console.log('3 characters instead of 5')
```

Large libraries usually alias commonly used globals like `undefined` and `window` as well for minification.

For example, you may see something like

```
(function($, a, b) { ... })(jQuery, window, undefined)
```

Answer (score 2):

`0` is falsey and `1` is truthy.

So, there is no need to convert them to boolean unless they are used in code like

```
if (h() === false) {
```

Or code converted when the code is minified as `true` and `false` are minified to `!1` and `!0` respectively.

Comment: I don't think `h()` is used to compared to `false`, there is no mean as in `h` there is no other data to compare.